# MVVM Page Navigation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation

Have begun a WPF app following mvvm pattern and have hit an issue. I have a Customers page which has a number of searches and returns a list of customers. When I double click a record I want to be able to navigate to the Customer view so user can view/edit details.

Is this possible without using MVVMLight or WAF or PRISM(as I have struggled for a bit getting head into PRISM fully!!!) without forcing my view model to have knowledge of my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a seperate / underlaying shell view & viewmodel with just the structure of your ui layout (some grids for positioning navigation, menu, search or content areas)

Then position your application views / controls the shell view. (maybe with some Visibility Bindings)

The main purpose of the shell viewmodel is to coordinate the flow of your ui. For example what control should hide or show based on some events of its child controls.

You could use an eventhandler in your search, wich is registered in the shell viewmodel, to show / hide your different content views.

Another approach could be a ContentPresenter.

Comment: Cheers menty, I like the sound of shell approach, was thinking along the lines of something similar where I would make the view models aware of the "App" and get a hook into it's navigationService like that. This sound feasible you think or should I create a navigation service wrapper......?

Comment: Hi, it depends on your overall architecture. You could use an observer pattern, wich attaches to your navigation service and your viewmodels. A message based architecture could be another possiblity where the navigation push messages and your viewmodels subscribe to their matching message types. In some scenarios you could also add some "App" dependencies in your viewmodels, but be aware of "dirting" them to much. In most cases the viewmodels do not need to know their surrounding. (This makes unit testing much easier,too.)

Answer (score 1):

Some people use [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) to connect VMs with Views in a decoupled way. Take a look at [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647347.aspx)